# html meta viewport user-scalable=no seemed no longer working on iOS 13.3

Tags: html, ios, viewport, meta-tags, device-width

I am trying to disable user pinch zoom on a web page dedicated for mobile devices, i tried the following meta tags with no avail:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

I also tired this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

some of my older websites that used to succeed in disabling user pinch zooming before, no longer work anymore as of today.

I am not sure if there's any new standards for achieving the same effect, but i dont seem to find any newer solution on the internet that would work with iOS 13.3.